# L'Hopsital Rule Understanding

Tags: calculus

Teacher taught us that if we ran into trouble finding the limit of a function we can take the power rule of derivative on the top and button of a fraction and then find the limit again.

But I don't understand, what does limit has to do with derivatives when the limit can't even be found?  Can someone explain it to me?

So if I can't find the limit of $\displaystyle \frac{x^3}{x^5}$ approaches infinity I can take the derivative of top and bottom until I can?  But why is that?  Isn't derivative just some kind of slope and limit is finding the missing point in graph?  what do they have to do with each other?

Comment: Take any decent calculus book and look for "l'Hospital's rule"...or google it: there are hundreds of thousands of sites. This is one of the most helpful rules to calculate limits, but it has its own conditions.

Comment: Thanks for all the time and effort you've helped me, thank you very much Don!

Comment: My pleasure, @user40424

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to explain why l'Hospital's rule is true in simple english: I think it's more the field of complicated mathematical proof.

Comment: It's not that complicated, but there're more than 1 case to prove and it's lengthly ... okay I guess it's complicated

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a proof for the case when $x \to a$, but please don't take this proof seriously because it's a naive one.

So, suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)=0$. So if you want to find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ you can do as follows:

$$\large\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac{f(x)-0}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-0}{x-a}}=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}}=\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)} $$

In the first step, we add $0$ to the numerator and denominator, which is arithmetically fine because $0$ doesn't change anything when it's summed. Then we divide both the numerator and denominator by $x-a$ which is again OK because it's like you're multiplying by $1$ and multiplying by $1$ doesn't change anything. Then I'm using the theorem that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)}$ which is again fine and at the end I use the definition of $f'(a)$

Now, notice that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0}f(t)$ where $\displaystyle t= \frac{1}{x}$. So you can generalize what I said with a suitable substitution.

Anyway, my proof isn't really rigorous for an analyst, but I guess it gives you an idea of what's going on without using any further theorems like Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: In case that you are dealing with $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ you can deal with it as $\large \lim_{x \to a}\displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=\frac{0}{0}$ and continue as before.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to find the limit

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x^3 + x}
$$

by direct substitution, we get $\frac{0}{0}$, which is an indeterminate form. So we use l'Hopital's rule and get $\frac{\cos x}{1 + 2x^2}$, which we can directly evaluate to be $1$.

Let's take a closer look at what just happened by writing using the taylor expansion. Our original limit then becomes

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0 + x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \cdots}{0 + x + x^3}
$$

our first approximation, $\frac{0}{0}$, is sort of like using the zeroth-order approximation $\sin x \approx 0$ and $x^3 + x \approx 0$ for small $x$. Of course it's true, but it's not powerful enough. When we use the slightly more powerful first-order approximation $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$ and $x^3 + x \approx 0$ for small $x$. Now this approximation is more accurate and powerful enough to evaluate the limit.

By differentiating, we replace the original limit with

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots}{1 + 3x^2}
$$

notice how what used to be the first-order terms became zeroth order terms. Every iteration of l'Hopital's rule destroys the zeroth-order term, allowing the higher-order terms to finally be heard.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I remember, L'hopital's rule doesn't require our functions to be analytic. It only needs differentiability. While, on the other hand, using Taylor's theorem you are using the fact that the function is analytic at that point, which is much stronger than being differentiable.

Comment: I know, this is how I express the intuition that "the first-order term determines the limit" which I think of when using l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I guess from the question it's evident that the OP doesn't know about Taylor's theorem and $o$ and $O$ notations yet. We don't really need to involve Taylor's theorem for this. Instead of Taylor's theorem one can talk about differential and linear approximation too, but I don't think we need that either. Look at my proof, it doesn't require anything advanced except the things high school students know at 9th grade.

Comment: then you need to talk about quadratic, cubic, quartic...etc approximations. I know the proof of taylor's theorem isn't very simple, but I find the fact that any nice function has a first, second, etc order approximation to be self-evident

Comment: Why do I need to talk about quadratic, cubic, quartic, .. approximations? I didn't get that part. Any 'nice' function isn't a good term, someone might say [x] is a nice function because it's useful, but unfortunately it's not differentiable at infinitely many points.

Comment: Because if you apply l'Hopital's rule twice, you are eliminating the zeroth and first order terms, and focusing on the quadratic terms of the functions

Comment: But you can apply l'Hopital's rule on $f'(x)/g'(x)'$ as it is a new problem again, avoiding explicitly talking about second order terms which is not suitable for high school level.

Comment: Your proof doesn't work for applying l'Hopital's rule twice, your final expression is a ratio of derivatives without a limit in front.

Comment: You can apply the same thing to $f'(x)$ and it works just fine. Seriously, I have no interest in a longer discussion over this. I just wanted to let you know that your proof is in a much higher level than what high school students know and also it uses a very strong condition that $f$ must be analytic around $x=a$, which is not required for L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I think any proof or proof intuition for l'Hopital's rule must be roughly as complex as mine. Your proof shows that $\lim f/g = f'/g'$, but l'Hopital's rule is that $\lim f/g = \lim f'/g'$. The later is much harder to prove than the former. In fact, I think you should point out this limitation in your answer

Comment: You're wrong. You can prove L'Hopital's rule rigorously with Cauchy's Mean Value theorem and that is much simpler than what you're proposing, and doesn't require $f$ and $g$ being analytic either. But as I said, I'm not interested in discussing this anymore, I want to use my time for something better. Have a nice time.

Comment: Fair enough. But why doesn't your answer point out this limitation of your proof? I can comment on your answer instead if you want.

Comment: That's not true, $f'/g'$ might be undefined while $\lim f'/g'$ exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10727/discussion-between-zodiac-and-some1-new4u)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking this is because when you are dealing with limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x \to x_0$ and $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$, $x$ approaches $x_0$ very close, so $x-x_0$ is becoming very small and $f(x)-f(x_0)$ is also becoming small, so yes, you can go along the tangent line with the slope $f'(x)$:
$$f(x) = f(x0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0) + ...$$

$$g(x) = g(x_0) + g'(x_0)(x-x_0) + ...$$

Don't forget you have $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$.
If you are dealing with limit at $f(x), g(x) \to \infty$, you should rewrite
$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1/g(x)}{1/f(x)} $$

This is of course not a strict proof